# Creating UIViewController with delegate

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `ViewController` that calls a custom class `PopOverModal` and passes in itself and a child ViewController.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   ...
    @IBAction func testPopOver(_ sender: Any) {
       var childVC = // initialize child view controller with view from storyboard
       var myPopOverModal = PopOverModal(parent: self, child: childVC);
    }
   ...
}
```

I need the childVC to delegate some tasks to the PopOverModal.

```
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    weak var delegate: PopOverModal?
    ...
}

class PopOverModal {
    init(parent: UIViewController, child: UIViewController) {        
        child.delegate = self
        child.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The initializer for the PopOverModal gives an error because UIViewController has no property `delegate`.

So then I did the following:

```
protocol PopOverViewController: class {
    weak var delegate: PopOverModal? {get set}
}

class ChildViewController: UIViewController, PopOverViewController {
    ...
    weak var delegate: PopOverModal?
    ...
}

class PopOverModal {
    init(parent: UIViewController, child: PopOverViewController) {        
        child.delegate = self
        child.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

However, now I get the error that `dismiss` is not a function of PopOverViewController.

What can I do to be able to access both the functions and properties of UIViewController and PopOverViewController while making sure that ChildViewController inherits from UIViewController?

I know I can create a Hybrid class that inherits from UIViewController and conforms to PopOverViewController and have my ChildViewController inherit that, but is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is guaranteed that `child` will be an instance of `ChildViewController` class then you can modify your initializer signature so that it accepts corresponding object:

```
init(parent: UIViewController, child: ChildViewController) {        
  child.delegate = self
  child.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

If it could be an arbitrary UIViewController but `delegate` is actual only for instances of `ChildViewController` then you can use type casting with either optional chaining or optional binding:

```
// Option #1 - optional chaining
init(parent: UIViewController, child: UIViewController) {
  (child as? ChildViewController)?.delegate = self
  child.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// Option #2 - optional binding
init(parent: UIViewController, child: UIViewController) {
  if let child = child as? ChildViewController {
     child.delegate = self
  }
  child.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

By the way, it is considered as a best practice to use protocol-based delegation. Here's an example of how it could be done:

```
protocol PopOverDelegate: class {
  // add any methods and properties that the delegate should implement
  func didPressButton()
}

class ChildViewController: UIViewController {
  ...
  weak var delegate: PopOverDelegate?
  ...
  // call delegate methods where you need them
  func onButtonPress() {
    self.delegate?.didPressButton()
  }
}

class PopOverModal: PopOverDelegate {
  init(parent: UIViewController, child: UIViewController) {        
    (child as? ChildViewController)?.delegate = self
    child.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  // MARK: - delegate methods
  func didPressButton() {
    print(#function)
  }
}
```